# Directory with PHP Include

Tags: php, php-include

I forgot to ask this in my question here:
[PHP Dynamic Include Help on Index.php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055684/php-dynamic-include-help-on-index-php)

How do I make it so directories are used with php includes? For example. I want to rename page2 to rules, then put the rules.php file into a folder called /rules/, so its now /rules/rules.php

As a result, the new url would be something like index.php?category=rules&id=rules

Here is the new code.

```
    <?php
    $page='';
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $page = $_GET['id'];
    }
    $pageArray = array('index','css-pub1','page2','page3','page4','page5','page6');
    $inArray = in_array($page, $pageArray);
    if ($inArray == true) {
    include(''. $page .'.php');
    } 
    else {
    include('main.php');
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This is a horribly stupidly insecure example, but... `include($_GET['category'] . '/' . $_GET['id'] . '.php')`

Comment: He can make that more secure by having a similar `in_array()` check for categories.

Comment: Problem is that I do not have any idea how to do any of that :(.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it, but to make it more secure you hace to check the page-category pair existance before the `include` (and maybe you should use `include_once` instead)

```
<?php
$page='';
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $page = $_GET['id'];
}
if (isset($_GET['category'])){
    $category = $_GET['category'];
}
$pageArray = array('index','css-pub1','page2','page3','page4','page5','page6');
$categoryArray = array('cat1','cat2','cat32');

$inArrayPage = in_array($page, $pageArray);
$inArrayCategory = in_array($category, $categoryArray);
if ($inArray && $inArrayCategory) {
    include(''. $page .'/'.$category.'.php');
} 
else {
    include('main.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean make sure those categories and pages exist? Just to elaborate.

Comment: yes, example:
`category=rules&id=rules` is a valid pair but
`category=auto-parts&id=rules` is not

Comment: I tried your method above, but when I go to index.php?category=rules&id=rules, it shows up with the content of main.php